# How to record the sound of a specific application in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording

Is there a way to record the sound of a particular application in Windows7? I'm aware of Stereo Mix option, but I'm interested in recording a specific app directly. In the volume control panel (Sound Mixer) you can mute a specific app, so there has to be some system procedure to separate the streams.

Is it possible to record each app separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complicated task, but totally possible if the Application you want to record supports choosing a specific audio device. Alternatively, some software will not rescan the devices and will record the default device at the time the device is acquired.

You can then use [Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) as a virtual sound card to pipe the audio though. Use a generic recording software (i.e. Audacity) to record the audio off the virtual audio cable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need [totalrecorder](http://www.totalrecorder.com/productfr_tr.htm) software for your help. This will record any sound passing through your line/mic etc..

Comment: Is there any free alternative?

Comment: This program doesn't even satisfy your needs. It's just an audio recorder.